# Cambiar formato en que me devuelve la fecha el calendario bootstrap-material-datetimepicker

Tags: date, datepicker, material-design, momentjs

Hola trabajo con el framwork symfony3 y me esta dando problemas un campo de tipo date que para el formulario utilizo datepicker cuando selecciono en el calendario la fecha, lo que recibo es un string y realmente necesito que sea tipo date y debido a esto me da un error de que no es valido el campo. Yo utilizo para el calendario las librerias bootstrap-material-datetimepicker y moment
Formulario

```
  - ->add('fechainicio', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType', array(
            'format'=>'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'widget'=>'single_text'))
```

Vista plantilla twig

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group form-float">
                                <div  class="form-line "  >
                                    {{ form_widget(form.fechainicio,{'attr':{'class': 'datepicker form-control','placeholder':'Fecha Inicio del Proyecto'}})}}
                                    {{ form_errors(form.fechainicio) }}
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Podrías compartir el código en vez de una imagen?

Comment: ya colgué el código...agradecida si me ayudas en esto, el calendario me sale perfectamente solo es como me esta devolviendo la fecha que me la da como un string y por supuesto es de tipo Datetime. Para que tengas una idea cuando selecciona la fecha me devuelve jueves 26 abril 2018 y lo que quiero que sea 26-04-2018

Answer (score 1):

Al invocar el script del datepicker puedes pasarle como opción el formato en que quieres que te devuelva la fecha. En tu caso algo como:

```
{% block js %}
   {{ parent() }}
    <script>
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Si no necesitas la complejidad del datepicker puedes usar el input de tipo fecha de html5
```<input class="form-control" name="fechainicio" type="date">```